# How can I write those bytes in this case in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new in C#, And I have tried many solutions but couldn't do it, this is my code , How to write this four (bytes) declared in first method but I want write them to file in second method.

```
        private void openfiles()
    {

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open";
        ofd.Filter = "Bin files|*.bin";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = ofd.FileName;
            using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                long size = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;
                long ssize = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length / 1024;
                int allsize = unchecked((int)size);
                byte[] bytes = b.ReadBytes(4);
            }
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw =new BinaryWriter(File.Open("FileName.bin",FileMode.Create)))
        {
            
          
            bw.Write(bytes);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to store the `bytes` variable somewhere, most likely as a member of a class.

Comment: You should go read up about "scope" and what that means in C#

Comment: you should store those 4 bytes somewhere, the easiest way would be a private variable that can be accesed withing those two methods. That being said, if your code compiles, you may already be doing it because in your `button2_Click` event you are doing `bw.Write(bytes);` so I assume that if you changed your `openFiles()` method to `bytes = b.ReadBytes(4);` you should be fine.

Comment: @Cleptus If you please may you provide an example , Because when I stored the variable as public I got an error [Cant write NULL bytes]

Comment: With `byte[] bytes =... ` you are declaring a *new* variable that is valid just in that using-block ("scope") . Remove that `byte[]` (and keep the rest) to use your class-level field

Comment: You need to store the bytes in memory for use in writing.

Comment: Do you want to just write those four bytes, or do you want to overwrite the existing bytes but keep the rest of the file intact?

Comment: @JAlex  I'll  seek to specific offset overwrite other four bytes in the file, I can do this but inside same function

Answer (score -1):

First you *need* to have somewhere to store the data after it is read and until it is written again. Best guess would be a field in the form, but that is design decision you need to make.

Next split up your code into functional parts, and don't put everything into button handlers. This way parts of the code can be re-used if needed.

Because the design intent is not clear, I have a very basic skeleton code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string _filename;
    byte[] _data;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Title = "Open";
        dlg.Filter = "Bin files|*.bin";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this._filename = dlg.FileName;
            this._data = ReadHeader(_filename);
            MessageBox.Show($"Read {_data.Length} bytes from {_filename}");
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string destination = "Filename.bin";
        if (MessageBox.Show($"About to overwrite {destination} with data from {_filename}. Proceed?", "File Header", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            WriteHeader(destination, this._data);
        }
    }
    static byte[] ReadHeader(string filename)
    {
        byte[] fileHeader;
        var fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
        using (var fr = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            fileHeader = fr.ReadBytes(4);
        }
        fs.Close();
        return fileHeader;
    }

    static void WriteHeader(string filename, byte[] fileHeader)
    {
        var fs = File.OpenWrite(filename);
        using (var fw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            fw.Write(fileHeader);
        }
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```